# how to display data(from database) in datagrid using silverlight?

Tags: c#, wcf, mvvm, datagrid, silverlight-5.0

hi i am new to silver light. i want to display data from database in data grid. since ado.net cannot be used to retrieve data i am confused. 
I have tried ado.net concepts. but its not working. i found that i have to use wcf to fetch data. so can anybody give me a step by step example to do that? that too using mvvm model.
i have created a model, view model folder. in view model i want to acces data.

model has one class i.e below

```
namespace emp.Models
{
    public class Employee
       {
          public int EmpId { get; set; }
           public String EmpFName { get; set; }
          public String EmpLName { get; set; }
        } 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all you must go through this link and come to know How to bind DataGrid [Working with DataGrid Control in Silverlight](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/working-with-datagrid-in-silverlight/) Now read this [MVVM AND Silverlight](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/MVVM-with-Silverlight-09a2493a)

Comment: second link not working. i have tried first example before..i know how to bind static data. i want to know how to bind data from database.

Comment: [Creating and Consuming a WCF Service in Silverlight](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=228)

Comment: i pasted a another link in above comments as well. If you still facing problem with binding let me know

Comment: can anybody give me some more example in MVVM? Simple examples..

Comment: [Try this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623924/Silverlight-with-MVVM-and-WCF)

Comment: [MVVM Silverlight Understading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight/archive/2011/02/28/getting-started-with-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications.aspx)

Comment: still bit confused with data access..where do we write the query in mvvm ? in view model or in separate class?

Comment: According to bestPractices ViewModel nothing to deal with Business Logic. ViewModel only for interact with View to display the data and handling events.

Comment: ya thanks. got it now..i tried one example. now its much more clear. :-)